# Excel Vba function Select Case

Tags: excel, vba, function, math, vba7

I need to rewrite this func in Excel VBA, but I don't know how

[image]

```
Public Function y(x As Double, y As Double) As Double
  Select Case x
  Case Is <= 1
    y = x
  Case 1 < x <= 2
    y = 2 * x
  Case Is > 2
    y = 3 * x
  End Select
End Function
```

Comment: Remove `, y As Double` from your function arguments. It serves no purpose and is effectively a duplicate declaration.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is the useless repetition of the tags plus the single word *function*, which conveys nothing of relevance. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title says nothing meaningful about your question.

Answer (score 4):

### Select Case in a Function

**The Function**

- It is not necessary (not possible) to use the 2nd part (`> 1`) of the 2nd condition because it is covered by the 1st condition. In VBA, you can never ever use `1 < x <= 2`. Instead, in an If statement, you could use `If x > 1 And x <= 2 Then`. You might encounter multiple conditions in a single case which you might want to utilize with `Case Is > 1, Is <= 2`. Unfortunately, the comma doesn't mean `And`, it means `Or` which is useless (incorrect) in this particular case.
- The 3rd condition covers all other possibilities (`Case Else`) that are not covered by the first two conditions. It is not wrong to use `Case Is > 2` instead.

```vb
Public Function y(ByVal x As Double) As Double
    Select Case x
        Case Is <= 1: y = x ' if not then (already) x > 1
        Case Is <= 2: y = 2 * x ' if not then x > 2
        Case Else: y = 3 * x
    End Select
End Function
```

**A Test**

```vb
Sub yTEST()
    Dim x As Double
    For x = 0.5 To 3 Step 0.5
        Debug.Print x, y(x)
    Next x
End Sub
```

**The Results**

```vb
 0.5           0.5 
 1             1 
 1.5           3 
 2             4 
 2.5           7.5 
 3             9
```